# How can I increase floating number with ctrl-a without deleting zeros?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

When I'm trying to increase numbers with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> it removes the leading and the trailing zeros.

For example:

```
1.009500
1.09500
1.0009500
```

Results after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>:

```
1.009500  ->  1.9501
1.09500   ->  1.9501
1.0009500 ->  1.9501
```

or if cursor in front of the `.`

```
1.009500  ->  2.009500
1.09500   ->  2.09500
1.0009500 ->  2.0009500
```

Is there a way to make it work like this:

```
1.009500  ->  1.009501
1.09500   ->  1.09501
1.0009500 ->  1.0009501
```

I have tried this on

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 12 2015 04:35:19)
```

Comment: cannot reproduce. What Vim version is this?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I can reproduce with a version 7.4.1558 and `nrformats=bin,octal,hex`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you for your comment. I've edited my question.

Comment: @statox, same here, what is strange is that I have the same result with `009500`, but not with `0001`, `000100`... For the two last one the increment keeps the leading `0`

Comment: @nobe4 probably treating them as octal numbers..

Comment: @spasic I think so yes.

Comment: Three cheers for Vim defaults.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that this is caused by my configuration of 'nrformats'. I've never understood, why octal was part of 'nrformat' setting

Comment: It is worth noting that your question cannot actually be solved as stated - you can increment the floating point portion of the number, but not the full floating point number.  To see this, try incrementing 1.99 and you will get 1.100

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @statox's suggestion, you can solve your issue with:

```
:set nrformats-=octal
```

---

Firstly, Vim does not increment decimal number, it will try to increment `1` and `009500` separately. So the question is why incrementing `009500` removes the leading `0`.

As suggested by @sp asic, I think vim is treating this number as an octal number.

Looking at the source code of Vim, a [conversion between the string and the actual number is done](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/22fcfad29276bd5f317faf516637dcd491b96a12/src/ops.c#L5689), using the `str2nr()` function.

You can see the definition of numbers in `:h expr-number`:

```
                                            hex-number octal-number

Decimal, Hexadecimal (starting with 0x or 0X), or Octal (starting with 0).
```

`009500` is a number starting with a `0`, but containing a `9`, it's not an octal number, and should not have a leading `0`.

You can see the same result calling the `str2nr()` function yourself:

```
:echo str2nr(000100)
64
:echo str2nr(000900) 
900
```

`00100` is a valid octal number, incrementing it will just add `1` to the result.

`00900` is an *invalid* decimal number, incrementing it will *fix* it (removing the leading `0`) and incrementing it.

**Note:** This is what I've understood of the little dig I've done in the Vim code, as I didn't understood everything I've read I may be wrong.

---

I believe the code responsible for the decimal conversion is the following ([source](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/ee2615af64fdcee87d8e4b13b65356e77fbd969b/src/charset.c#L1937-L1943)):

```
while (VIM_ISDIGIT(*ptr))
{
    un = 10 * un + (uvarnumber_T)(*ptr - '0');
    ++ptr;
    if (n++ == maxlen)
    break;
}
```

Considering the result is `un`, you can see that the first `0` won't add any value to the decimal number.

Comment: So to solve the problem you can simply do `set nrformat-=octal`

Comment: typo.. `nrformats` or `nf`

Comment: @nobe4 OMG, thank you very much for your awesome answer. Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Wow. +1, this is a very informative and thorough answer.

Answer (score 4):

You found the answer, which is caused by the default Vim setting of `'nrformat'`.

However, I'd like to mention another possibility to overcome this problem. This would be to use visual mode, select the last number and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.

Note that this needs a relative recent Vim version, something like 7.4.1000, since visual mode incrementing/decrementing has been added just recently.