# Replace using info from the replaced string

Tags: regular-expression, replace

What I want to do is replace this:

```
<|Filename.ext|5|0|>
```

with

```
<|Filename.ext|5|0|>
<|Filename.ext|5|1|>
<|Filename.ext|5|2|>
<|Filename.ext|5|3|>
<|Filename.ext|5|4|>
```

I wrote a necessary regular expression:

```
<|\(\w\| \)\+\.\w\+|\d\{1,2}|0|>
```

So, substitution would go something like this:

```
 %s/<|\(\w\| \)\+\.\w\+|\d\{1,2}|0|>/REPLACEMENT/g
```

But what should *REPLACEMENT* actually be?

**EDIT:**
Please, note that *5* in the example could be any other number: I am looking for a general solution. So, this:

```
<|Filename.ext|n|0|>
```

---->

```
<|Filename.ext|n|0|>
<|Filename.ext|n|1|>
<|Filename.ext|n|2|>
...
<|Filename.ext|n|n-2|>
<|Filename.ext|n|n-1|>
```

Sorry for not making this clear right away.

Comment: A substitution won't help, here, unless you already have all the identical lines you need.

Comment: Not sure what was the purpose of your edit; as far as I understand, none of the answers below rely on the '*5*' to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Vim version `7.4.754` or later you can do this simply with some copy/paste and `g<C-a>`:

```
yy4pf0<C-v>3jg<C-a>
```

Decomposing:

```
yy4p      duplicate the line 4 time and put you on the 2nd line
f0        go to the 0
<C-v>3j   start a visual block selection and go down 3 lines
g<C-a>    increment successively (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

**Edit:**

OP ask for a "general" solution,

You can replace `4` and `3` by `N` and `N-1` to produce the same effect over `N` lines.

Have a look at : `:h v_g_CTRL-A`

Comment: Worth noting that you need a relatively recent version for this to work.

Comment: Nice catch, do you know where I can find this info?

Comment: Don't know exactly, but I knew about it because of [this post](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8868/6489) by Christian.

Comment: `<C-a>` is old.  IIRC `g<C-a>` appeared around 7.4 patch level ~800, and bugs about it have been fixed ever since.  It might be usable in the forthcoming Vim 8; until then there's always `visincr`, which does this and a lot more.

Comment: The documentation commit (https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/979243b990a68c20ea17fa26470639104e62b071) regarding this seems to point to version 7.4 also, I'll add it.

Comment: Not really.  7.4 has been released in 2013, the `g<C-a>` thing is a lot more recent.

Comment: Here it is: 7.4.754, from 2015-06-25.  Like I said, it was really buggy at first.

Comment: Nice, where did you find it?

Comment: I searched the docs, then `git blame`d the docs, then looked around that date in the logs. :) It helped that I actually knew what to look for.

Comment: Last week I've also searched for this info in order to disable increment.vim in newer versions, but instead of git I searched for `ctrl-a` in http://vimhelp.appspot.com/version8.txt.html (which was mentioned on vim-dev mailing list a few days ago).

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could do this is with a macro:

```
qqyyp$bb^aq
```

Then `n@q` where n is how many additional lines you want

- `qq`: record a macro in register "q"
- `yyp`: yank the current line and put it below
- `$bb`: move to the end of line and then back two "words" (This positions the cursor over the second number)
- `^a`: this is `<C-a>` and not a literal "^a". This increments the number by one.
- `q`: end the macro
- `@q`: play the macro at register "q". Can be prefaced with a number as stated before.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%s/|\(0\)|>/\="|".(submatch(1)+1)."|>"/
```

The idea is to use `\=`, which allows to use an arbitrary expression for the replacement part. Note that it doesn't allows `\1`, thus the use of `submatch()`.

More info: [`:help sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression).

Answer (score 0):

To add a solution only using `:s`, I would suggest

```
s/^.*$/\=map(range(0,split(getline("."),"|")[2]), 'join(split(getline("."), "|")[0:2] + [v:val] + split(getline("."), "|")[4:4], "|")')
```

This will work for any `foo|bar|x|0|end`, where `foo` and `bar` are string not containing the pipe character `|`, `x` is the number that indicates the number of repetitions, and `end` is an arbitrary string.