# Understand addition on numbers in Vim

Tags: number-formatting

I have a file with the following content:

```
001
```

Now if I start a macro (<kbd>qq</kbd>), yank this line (<kbd>Y</kbd>), paste it (<kbd>p</kbd>), increase the number by four (<kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>), end the macro (<kbd>q</kbd>), and execute this macro nine times (<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>), then I end up with following:

```
001
005
011
015
021
025
031
035
041
045
051
```

How does this work? I mean why is the third number six (`001` + `005`) digits larger than second number? Or fifth number six digits larger than fourth number, etc.?

Comment: see also: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8866/how-can-i-increase-floating-number-with-ctrl-a-without-deleting-zeros

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the number starts with a `0` it's interpreted as an octal number (base-8, instead of base-10). Vim also recognises hexadecimal numbers (base-16) if it starts with `0x` and binary numbers (base-2) if it starts with `0b`.

You can use the [`'nrformats'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27nrformats%27) setting to control which numbers Vim recognises; IMHO a value of `bin,hex` makes the most sense, as it's not easy to confuse a hex or binary in those formats with a regular base-10 number.

Also see the paragraphs below [`:help v_g_CTRL-X`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#v_g_CTRL%2dX) (no direct help tag).